# Software Center and cross-platform licensing of a commercial app

Tags: software-center, commercial

I currently use my own scheme for licensing where the user is emailed a license file upon purchase. The license file would allow the user to run the app on both Windows and Linux. Without the license, the app runs in save-disabled demo mode.

Can I distribute my app via the Software Center, or must purchasing of the app be via the Software Center as well?

Comment: You can always use a ppa which works in software center. See also - https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/publish/other-forms-of-submitting-apps/commercial-software-faqs/

Comment: @bodhi.zazen You cannot upload proprietary apps, to a PPA, without a commercial subscription to Launchpad. Also, any apps for purchase really should be sold via the app store, as then a portion of the price goes to Canonical, which pays for the development of Ubuntu.

Comment: @dobey - it is sort of 2 questions - "Can I distribute my app via the Software Center" yes with a ppa and the restrictions you cite. The OP always has that choice. 2"purchasing of the app be via the Software Center as well" well, yes that route goes via Canonical.